# Android load Shared Preferences on UI thread

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-sharedpreferences

Within my application, I have implemented a password screen but a check needs to be ran to see whether Activity A or Activity B should be shown and this check is obviously the result of a Shared Preference however, there is noticeable lag when opening the application - the code can be seen below but how can I optimise this for it to open quicker and without the lag?

**Launcher Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    boolean loggedIn = PreferenceUtils.getBoolean(LauncherActivity.this, PreferenceUtils.LOGGED_IN_STATE);
    boolean passwordEnabled = PreferenceUtils.getBoolean(LauncherActivity.this, PreferenceUtils.APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ENABLED);

    Log.d(TAG, "LOGGED IN: " + loggedIn + " " + "PW: " + passwordEnabled);
    if (!loggedIn) {
        // Start Login Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, ApplicationIntro.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        //PreferenceUtils.clearPreferences(LauncherActivity.this);
    } else {
        if (passwordEnabled) {
            // Start Password Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, PasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // Start Main Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    finish();
}
```

**Password Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_password);

    setupActionBar();

    setupPreferences();
    findViews();
    setupValues();
    setListeners();

}

...

private void setupPreferences() {
    attemptsRemaining = PreferenceUtils.getInt(PasswordActivity.this, PreferenceUtils.APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ATTEMPTS);
    storedPassword = PreferenceUtils.getString(PasswordActivity.this, PreferenceUtils.APPLICATION_PASSWORD);
    duressPassword = PreferenceUtils.getString(PasswordActivity.this, PreferenceUtils.DURESS_PASSWORD);
}
```

**Preference Utils**

```
public static void saveString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = new SecurePreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String getString(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = new SecurePreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key, "");
}

public static void saveBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = new SecurePreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public static boolean getBoolean(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = new SecurePreferences(context);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Check is blocking the UI Thread that's why the app lag. Its a good practice to do the lagy process in background Thread using `AsyncTask`[here is a link to AsyncTask documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
Feel free to ask further queries.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Are you able to provide some code of how you would suggest doing this? As I've used AsyncTask in the past to load these values and whilst it is quicker, on the Password Activity the user can actually see content being updated as a result of onPostExecute. If you could therefore suggest some code on how you would advise doing this, then that would be great - thanks. Also, the onCreate in the Launcher Activity is the only code in that file as it has no view whereas the PasswordActivity has a view (an EditText for the user to input the password and a TextView)

Comment: What is the flow of app.when app start which activity launch first and then after!

Comment: Launcher Activity > Shared Preference check to see whether to show Intro Activity or Password Activity > if Password Activity > Shared Preference gets the saved password to check against the user's input